# Creating array of objects without specified size

Tags: c++

I want to make an array of objects made from class, but i don't know how many of those objects will be in the array. I tried to make it with this code: `MyClass a[];`, but Qt Creator shows me an error: *flexible array member 'a' of type 'MyClass []' with non-trivial destruction* and a warning: *flexible array members are a C99 feature*. The code works with `MyClass a[n];` but that is not what i need.

Comment: Try `std::vector<MyClass> a;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you can make usage of `vector<MyClass>a`. 
Whenever you need to add any more object to the array use: `a.push_back(object)`

Basically when you declare a vector, a fix capacity container is created dynamically. Whenever the size of vector crosses the capacity, the entire vector is copied to a new location with increased size.